# label is not created in other form C# win form

Tags: c#, forms, windows-forms-designer

So, my problem is that i have a button in one form that needs to add a label in other form, label has a text that is from main labels textbox, and label has a backcolor that is from color block selected from main form.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PiezimesLogs log = new PiezimesLogs();//form where the label would be added
        Label l = new Label();// creates new label

        l.Text = piezimeTxt.Text;
        l.BackColor = ColorChange.BackColor;
        log.Controls.Add(l);
    }
```

so, this is the code from button that should do everything.
log - other form in which the label should be created.

c# win form

Comment: And what problems do you have with this code? Why don't you show the form created in this code?

Comment: `PiezimesLogs log = new PiezimesLogs();` creates a new form which you never show.

Comment: oh, ok, im sorry, im just new to programming, i thought that with that line i create a sort of like new name for that form. i have that from already created. ok, then how do i add label to that form which i already have, what do i need to do to access that form and add label in it?

Comment: and what is the flow for this?. Can you open new forms and manage DialogResult?. Then you can add labels with the text you need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new label, you could simply add an empty label to your 'target-form'.

Afterwards, you can simply modify the labels' text in order to make it appear.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: well, yes, i could do that, but my idea is to create new label every time i create new text in main form. the idea behind all of this is sort of like reminder, i put text in one form, and the text is added in other form where i could overlook all of my created reminders

Comment: Then better use a multiline TextBox with its ReadOnly property set to true. You could use the scroll bar when the reminders reach the max height of your form